# How to make a standalone autocad .net application

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am trying to make an application that a part of it needs some autocad features. So I tried anything in the internet for standalone application, but nothing happen and i always return an error.
(It is not plugin, just open pre-installed autocad and draw something) 
My first try:

```
AcadApplication gbl_app = new AcadApplication();
AcadDocument gbl_doc = gbl_app.ActiveDocument;
gbl_app.Application.Visible = true;
```

And this is error which raise in first line.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SBDesign.exe

Additional information: 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0D327DA6-B4DF-4842-B833-2CFF84F0948F} 
failed due to the following error: 80040154 
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

My second try:

```
 AcadApplication acAppComObj = null;
            const string strProgId = "AutoCAD.Application.20";

            // Get a running instance of AutoCAD
            try
            {
                acAppComObj = (AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(strProgId);
            }
            catch // An error occurs if no instance is running
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create a new instance of AutoCAD
                    acAppComObj = (AcadApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(strProgId), true);
                }
                catch(Exception er)
                {
                    // If an instance of AutoCAD is not created then message and exit
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Instance of 'AutoCAD.Application'" +
                                                         " could not be created.");

                    return;
                }
            }

            // Display the application and return the name and version
            acAppComObj.Visible = true;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Now running " + acAppComObj.Name +
                                                 " version " + acAppComObj.Version);
```

And this is the error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for 
the interface with IID '{10E73D12-A037-47E5-8464-9B0716BE3990}' 
failed due to the following error: 
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

So really how can i make a standalone application?

Thank you
a.h

Comment: "AutoCAD.Application.20" will only work with AutoCAD 2015 and 2016. Try using "AutoCAD.Application" to target any AutoCAD version (except LT).

Comment: When i use "AutoCAD.Application" nothing happen. My autocad is 2015

Comment: @gileCAD  I tried "AutoCAD.Application"  but i get same error that happen for "AutoCAD.Application.20" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IID {10E73D12-A037-47E5-8464-9B0716BE3990} is the IID of AutoCAD 2017 AcadApplication which seems to be not correctly installed.

You need to use the ProgId: AutoCAD.Application.20 and use the Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll and Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll 20.0.51.0 for your references to use your AutoCAD 2015 installation. I think you're actually using 21.0.52.0 (AutoCAD 2017).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer, My COM references are 20.0.51.0.0 but my Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.common.dll is 21.0.0.0. Take a look to my [ScreenShot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApRBiX7lvlBibweEWHo3Uaj0M-k). So from where can i get 20.0.51.0 ?

Comment: _Thank you!!!!! You solved. Sorry if i cant vote up, because my reputation is less than 15._Really i was hopeless and waiting for so many duplicated answers. But you rock man. For those who have my problem,Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll should be the same version of your autocad, so i just added references from   `DRIVE:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll`  and `DRIVE:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll`. AND everything work now.!!!!

Comment: My IDE always added references with wrong version, So i just decided to create a new project and copy whole the codes into new project, and everything works!!!!!